# c# loop comparisons

Tags: c#, combobox, while-loop

I use comboboxes a lot. I often loop through them to find a match based upon the SelectedValue, for example...

```
while(cmbCompany.SelectedValue.ToString()!=B1ID)
{ 
    cmbCompany.SelectedIndex++; 
}
```

a) am I missing some much quicker option!
b) if my comparison was against an integer, is there any benefit in declaring a string and setting that equal to the integer.ToString(), or if I just (in my example above) used B1ID.ToString() would the compiler optimise it for me?
c) or are string comparisons so slow that I'd be better off parsing (or casting) the SelectedValue to an integer?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmbCompany.SelectedValue = B1ID` ought to do the trick - does it not?

Comment: Not if SelectedValue needs converting to a string to match B1ID

Comment: Better to convert B1ID to something that'll match SelectedValue then.

Comment: thanks I hadn't realised I could use it that way round, I would have expected that to set the currently selected items value to B1ID, I now feel quite stupid, still we all have to learn. Sometimes the language is more 'intelegent' than I expect.

Comment: No problem - I'm always coming across quicker ways of doing something I've been doing the slow way for years.  :)

Answer (score 8):

The most confounding part of your algorithm is that you're incrementing the index with every comparison. This is very inefficient because you actually change the selection with every test which also fires events (if you have them wired) and potentially dangerous because reacting to the selection change event every time will make your logic unnecessarily complex.

There are a number of other ways. Here is a better (though rough) code sample from MSDN:

```
int index = comboBox1.FindString(textBox2.Text);
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
```

(Notice that this code snippet looks for the data in the collection first and then sets the SelectedIndex value.)

Comment: fabulous, thanks, yes I have to turn the events off and back on again, which i always thought was inneficient.
I've used FindStringExact to check for 'new' items typed into the comboboxes, but didn't realise I couled get the index back.
I now have a lot of changes to make :)

Answer (score 0):

a) Maybe, but I'll let others answer that part.

b) The compiler doesn't seem likely to hoist the `ToString` out of the loop.

c) Definitely slower to reparse each value.  Better to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

a/b) Have you tried using [FindString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxyt1t12.aspx)?  The method basically looks for something that *starts with (there is an equivelent one for Find exact).

Or you could search the "items" and do [FindByValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue.aspx)

```
  cmbCompany.Items.FindByValue
```

c)  Built in methods will be faster, as well as using native types (aka its more costly to cast and then compare)